# Best way to cover image inside responsive block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on the responsive slideshow on the header. I can't use CSS property `background` with `cover`. I should use `<img>` inside div.

```
<div class="parent">
  <img src="slide.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

I tried something like this:

```
var imageContainer = $('.header');

var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight();
var headerWidth = $('header').outerWidth();
var imgHeight = 498;
var imgWidth = 1900;
imageContainer.find('img').each(function() {
    var ratio = headerWidth / imgWidth;
    var newWidth = imgWidth * ratio;
    var newHeight = imgHeight * ratio;

    if (newHeight < headerHeight) {
        ratio = newHeight / imgHeight;
        $(this).css({
            'height'      : headerHeight,
            'margin-left': -(imgWidth * ratio / 2)
        }) 
    } else {
        $(this).css({
            'width'      : newWidth,
            'margin-left': -(newWidth/2)
        })
    }

})
```

For example, parent's block is 2500x400 and the image is 1900x1400. Or parent's block is 400x400.

I want to find the best solution for responsive images inside block.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest using bootstrap as your frontend can really help you. http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: if you are about the carousel it uses `max-width` for images, nothing about height.

Comment: You mean something like this? http://www.themearmada.com/demos/sharkfin/

Comment: No, they use image inside div with background-color. I need something like this - http://mediatemple.net But they use `background-size: cover`. And the image looks ugly in big screens

Comment: Okay, I think I get your point. Something like this? http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/backgrounds.html If that is what you want, I suggest combining bootstrap and fullpage.js by alvaro trigo will save you lots of work.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use CSS rule for responsive images

```css
.parent {
background-image: url(slide.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto;
}
```

try [Playit W3C Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=auto)

Comment: I can't use `background` because it's carousel with animation.